# Django: annotate queryset with string

Tags: python, django

I need to annotate a queryset with strings from dictionary. The dictionary keys come from the model's field called 'field_name'.

I can easily annotate with strings from dictionary using the Value operator:

```
q = MyModel.objects.annotate(
  new_value=Value(value_dict[key], output_field=CharField()))
```

And I can get the field value from the model with F expression:

```
q = MyModel.objects.annotate(new_value=F('field_name'))
```

Putting them together however fails:

```
# doesn't work, throws
# KeyError: F(field_name)    
q = MyModel.objects.annotate(
  new_value=Value(value_dict[F('field_name')],
                  output_field=CharField()))
```

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186782/combining-django-f-value-and-a-dict-to-annotate-a-queryset%5D) question, which afaiu tries to do the same thing but that solution throws another error:

```
Unsupported lookup 'field_name' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here but I just can't get it to work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Well a dictionary does not understand a Django `F` value, since Python evaluates `value_dict[F('field_name')]`, that thus means it raises an error. You *can* do this by using a `Case(When(..))` ssequence, but I really doubt if this will be an improvement.

Comment: `Case(When(` is the idea behind the solution in the linked question. Couldn't get that to work either..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, just as I thought, a tiny piece was missing. The `Case(When(...` solution in the linked question worked, I just needed to wrap the dictionary value in Value() operator as follows:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.annotate(
    new_value=Case(
        *[ When(field_name=k, then=Value(v)) for k,v in value_dict.items() ],
        output_field=CharField()
    )
)
```