# Enrich Django QuerySet different outcomes

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

**Goal**

Querying for all products, slicing them, returning subset of those products with an added `key:value` , in other words, enriched.

**Code that works but I can't use**

I can't use this code because I use a paginator, the paginator accesses the `count` of the `QuerySet`. If I pass the **sliced QuerySet** then that count is just for that sliced part, not the overall `QuerySet`, hence why I can't use it.

```
products_qs = final_qs[paginator.get_offset(request):
                       paginator.get_offset(request) + paginator.get_limit(request)]
for product in products_qs:
    product.raw['super_cool_new_key'] = ms_response.get('results').get(product.id)
```

This works great, when I print the data I can see that `super_cool_new_key` enrichment in every product. Awesome. Problem? Well, I have had to slice it and now the **count** method is no longer true. Of course, I can do something like:

```
products_qs.count = final_qs.count
```

and move on with my life, but it feels... hacky, or maybe not?

**Code I would like for it to work, but doesn't**

```
for i in range(paginator.get_offset(request),
               paginator.get_offset(request) + paginator.get_limit(request)):
    product = final_qs[i]
    product.raw['super_cool_new_key'] = ms_response.get('results').get(product.id)
```

When I see the output of the data, the `super_cool_new_key` is not there. I can't wrap my head around as to why?

Maybe I am having a thick day and I don't understand accessing by reference, so I remove the middlemonkey.

```
final_qs = final_qs.all()
for i in range(paginator.get_offset(request),
               paginator.get_offset(request) + paginator.get_limit(request)):
    final_qs[i].raw['super_cool_new_key'] = ms_response.get('results').get(final_qs[i].id, '')
```

**Suspicions**

It's obvious it's something about the code difference that is the culprit of why one way works and the other way doesn't. My dollar is on the following:

- The slice
- The iteration

Looking into [Django Docs for QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/) :

> Iteration. A QuerySet is iterable, and it executes its database query the first time you iterate over it.

Then about slicing:

> Slicing. As explained in Limiting QuerySets, a QuerySet can be sliced, using Python’s array-slicing syntax. Slicing an unevaluated QuerySet usually returns another unevaluated QuerySet, but Django will execute the database query if you use the “step” parameter of slice syntax, and will return a list

I can't be the slicing then, because I don't do a slice with  a "step" parameter. Since it returns an **unevaluated QuerySet** the code I want to work, should in theory work. (Isn't that always the case?ha ha)

Ok so that clears up the fact that when, in the first option of coding, I did an iteration of `for x in x_container` the `QuerySet` was executed. Could that be the answer? So I modified the code:

**Spoiler Alert: still does not work**

```
final_qs = final_qs.all()
for i in range(paginator.get_offset(request),
               paginator.get_offset(request) + paginator.get_limit(request)):
    product = final_qs[i]
    product.raw['super_cool_new_key'] = ms_response.get('results').get(product.id)
```

Emmm... help?

**A suggested answer that, spoiler alert, did not work**

```
from django.db.models import When, Case, Value, CharField
when = [ When(id=k, then=Value(v)) for k,v in ms_response.get('results').items()]
p = final_qs[paginator.get_offset(request)
             :paginator.get_offset(request) + paginator.get_limit(request)]
p = p.annotate(super_cool_new_key=Case(
            *when,
            default=Value(''),
            output_field=CharField()
        )
    )
```

I also tried it without **slicing** but with `.all().annotate()` . Still didn't work. It doesn't work, not due to an Exception happening, but because when I see the output, that `super_cool_new_key` is not there, meaning it didn't enrich the objects, which is the whole point.

Comment: would you consider accessing the ms_response in the template? So anytime you need the results you would just access the ms_response based on the product.id in the template instead of worrying about merging the two. That way your QuerySet stays a queryset and you dont have to worry about pagination

Comment: Not possible in this current project, there is no template, a single endpoint that needs all this info nicely packed into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for is similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48187723/3130972) which utilizes [When](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when) and [Case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case). For your use it will be something along the following:

```
from django.db.models import When, Case, Value, CharField

ms_response = {5458: 'abc', 9900: 'def'}
whens = [
    When(id=k, then=Value(v)) for k, v in ms_response.items()
]
qs = YourModelName.objects.all().annotate(
    super_cool_key=Case(
        *whens,
        default=Value('xyz'),
        output_field=CharField()
    )
)
```

when you then call `qs.get(id=5458).super_cool_key` it will then return `'abc'`

Comment: Hi! I did try it out and learned about whens/cases along the way, but it didn't work :( I am updating my current question to include the new code.

Comment: care to share your error message? hard to tell why it is not working without more detail

Comment: Oh, there's no error, it executes just fine, but I don't see the new "super_cool_key" on the output.

Comment: How are you trying to access it "on the output"?

Comment: this is a tested, functional answer. please provide more information on how you are accessing the output