# Tyring to group database results by age in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to get a count all the items in the database for a given user, grouped into buckets depending on a timestamp.

I have a dictionary which defines a set of categories like this:

```
age_categories = {'cat1': {'start': <timestamp>, 'end': <timestamp>}},
                 {'cat2': {'start': <timestamp>, 'end': <timestamp>}},
                 ...
```

I want to get a result from the database that looks like this:

```
User      | cat1 | cat2 | cat3 | ...
Joe Smith |   12 |    0 |   7  | ...
Bob Smith |    4 |    9 |  11  | ...
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186782/combining-django-f-value-and-a-dict-to-annotate-a-queryset), I've tried:

```
age_query = [key=Count(Case(When(datefield__range=(val['start'], val['end']), then=1))) for key, val in age_categories.items()]
...
results = Table.objects.filter(...).values(...).annotate(*age_query)
```

but I can't get that to work. It gives me an invalid syntax error on the line where I define `age_query`.

If I change the query to be a list of strings as

```
age_query = [key + "=Count(Case(When(datefield__range=('" + val['start'] + "', '" + val['end'] + "'), then=1)))" for key, val in age_categories.items()]
```

it tells me that `Complex annotations require an alias` when the intent is that the dictionary key should be the alias.

Is this achievable? I know how I'd do it in raw SQL, but I'd really rather use Django's tools if at all possible.

Thanks.

Python 3.6.5
Django 1.11.6

Comment: This seems to be unclear. I'd request you to paste your raw sql or some sample data to give more clarity.